# Problem with sending argument using dblquad integrator

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

```
from scipy import integrate

def g(y,x,a):
    
    return x*y**2 + a

a= 13

integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 2, lambda x: 0, lambda x: x, args=(a))
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5 a= 13
6
----> 7 integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 2, lambda x: 0, lambda x: x, args=(a))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in dblquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, args, epsabs, epsrel)
599                 hfun(args[0]) if callable(hfun) else hfun]
600
--> 601     return nquad(func, [temp_ranges, [a, b]], args=args,
602             opts={"epsabs": epsabs, "epsrel": epsrel})
603

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in nquad(func, ranges, args, opts, full_output)
824     else:
825         opts = [opt if callable(opt) else _OptFunc(opt) for opt in opts]
--> 826     return _NQuad(func, ranges, opts, full_output).integrate(*args)
827
828

TypeError: integrate() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Comment: use `args=(a,)` to create a 1-tuple

Answer (score 0):

You could just define `a` inside (or even outside) of `g`:

```py
from scipy import integrate

a = 13

def g(y, x):
    return x * y ** 2 + a


integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 2, lambda x: 0, lambda x: x)
```

(I was never a big of the `args` argument.)